# Simply Login feature not working (not redirecting or storing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm developing a ruby app to have a sign-in/up feature but it won't seem to work and I have been attempting this for a few days now and can't figure it out.

It's not redirecting, displaying "successful" or error messages, or storing the information.

**I was using this tutorial:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pj7ueR-t2hk&index=17&list=PLmkbEVFV7DtBInYgh0OTQmO4olUjnKKrT

**Then used this to see if I was missing anything:** https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#code-user_show_action

GitHub to app files: https://github.com/brandnamewater/App3
​

**Here's my files:**

​

```
**User_controller**: https://pastebin.com/8MmvFmZw 


   **Models User**: https://pastebin.com/NCLufULp

   **View/users/new**: https://pastebin.com/a2vDCY7H

   **views/users/show** (not important): https://pastebin.com/VbwGXdca

   **Routes**: https://paste.ee/p/jyDwA

   **Schema**: https://paste.ee/p/fGCn9 ​
```

If there is anything else please let me know.

When i click "submit", nothing happens.  I get this URL:

http://localhost:3000/users/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=kdWiGeodxikOtAFggY27ED8SXukswQ3G1zsMJwNz5%2FvHW3%2BoUGtoVMMgBfIiFTmZmvbxy8OgcR%2B%2BB5%2FvH5BQFQ%3D%3D&user%5Buserid%5D=test121&user%5Bemail%5D=test123%40gmail.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=123456&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=123456&commit=Create+Account

When i run "rails c" and check how many users,  it says 1 (from the 1 admin account i created directly from rails c in the cmd)

I know this is not relevant to why it's not working but i did add a views/user/show file that contains this (just want to show as much as possible in case it helps)

```
<% provide(:title, @user.email) %>
<h1>

  <%= @user.email %>
</h1>
```

Comment: Whats the ouput of `rake routes`?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: haha, you might have as well shared your git repo link.

Comment: @DennyMueller here is my rake routes: https://paste.ee/p/m5CS7

Comment: @Surya Haha, I do have it in there - but not updated.  I may include it if i need to. :)

Comment: @Surya That's the issue! There is no error message, success message, redirect (just reloads the same page with blank fields) or entries/storing.  But this is the closest thing, my CMD after i pass through and add a test signup user: https://pastebin.com/mQpgqv9A

Comment: Git : https://github.com/brandnamewater/App3

Comment: I am curious where you get `signup_path` from? Because you pass this path as url to your form but this path does not exists so I guess it defaults to `users#new` path but you want to end up in the `users#create` action. Also the routes.rb in the pastebin is different to the one in your github repository.

Comment: @DennyMueller Check my github App3... I added the signup_path for kicks because the second tutorial mentioned it (i am new).  Did it just to see it anything would change, nothing happened so it was pointless.  I was just desperate.  The git hub is the official.  The pastebin is wacky

Comment: Did you see anything wrong with the github app3? I went over that video tutorial on the signin feature a bunch of times already and haven't found anything that stood out to me.  I'm doing something wrong but cannot see what it is!

Comment: You definitely should sort out some things. There is tons of different versions and explanations going on here. Different git and different pastebins. To answer your question: Your `rake routes` does not have signup_path so your login form cant work since the url option seems to be ommited and defaults to the `users#new` path. Since this action only assigns a variable your app actually works like expected from the code. I guess I am out of here since this wacky question just pulls other users into wacky solution guessing. This is not how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) just to see how things work. For notice in your create action in USerController i don't know if it should as you put it but you can try this :

```
flash[:success] = "User, created successfully"
```

And you should try this too, in your routes.rb file :

```
resources :users except[:create]
```

However it is a little hard to follow all your code.

Comment: I previously tried the flash[... but it also did not work.

resources :users except[:create] created an error and won't load

I have not installed devise, I will take a look.  Haven't heard of it. thanks

Comment: there is no app folder in the your git repo. may be you should reconsider pushing new project since they are lot missing files

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Solved: https://github.com/brandnamewater/App3

Comment: not one bit ha ;( sorry for confusion.  i meant solved as in i fixed the github rep

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `GET`, but not `POST` in your form:`<form method="get"...>` instead `<form method = "post"....>`, because:

> When i click "submit", nothing happens. I get this URL:
>   utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=kdWiGeodxikOtAFggY27ED8SXukswQ3G1zsMJwNz5%2FvHW3%2BoUGtoVMMgBfIiFTmZmvbxy8OgcR%2B%2BB5%2FvH5BQFQ%3D%3D&user%5Buserid%5D=test121&user%5Bemail%5D=test123%40gmail.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=123456&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=123456&commit=Create+Account

All params are in the `URL`.

Comment: Routes doesn't matter. This is part of the HTML (your views). Form sends data depends on its `method` attribute. You need to set it to POST.

Comment: Here's my git app for: https://github.com/brandnamewater/App3 ​

You're saying to change my view/users/new.html.erb files form_for?

orrr something else?

RN, its this: <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

Which is how the tutorial displays it too.  But i posted my github above and everyhing should be in there.  I''m not understanding this.  I've looked into this for answers on a few tutorials and i'm apparently doing everything right - from what i see

Comment: `form_for @user, method: "post"`